# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError No interface method build(). No interface method build()Landroid/app/Notification

Tags: android, crash, nosuchmethoderror, crashlytics-android

I'm noticing a strange crash report on production. I've tried to look it up, but I haven't found anything in source code. For me it looks like vendors of these devices just modified something in their SDK.

But it happens in support library. So how can this happen ?

### Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method build()Landroid/app/Notification; in class Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationBuilderWithBuilderAccessor; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationBuilderWithBuilderAccessor' appears in /data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk)
   at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$BuilderExtender.build(NotificationCompat.java:469)
   at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplApi21.build(NotificationCompat.java:768)
   at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:1559)
   at com.myapp.NotificationListener$MyNotification.updateText(MyNotification.java:106)
```

### Code where it happens:

```
Builder mBuiler = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
```

...

```
private Notification updateText(String title, String message) {
        return mBuidler
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new BigTextStyle(mBuidler)
                        .bigText(message))
                .build();
}
```

### Reproduces mostly on following devices:

- Samsung SM-G925F
- Samsung SM-G935F
- Samsung GT-I9300
- Some Lenovo devices
- Solarin phone (whatever it is)

### Operating systems:

- Android 6 - 95%
- Android 4 - 3%
- Android 5 - 2%

### I have millions of users and only few of them are getting this crash.

Answer (score 2):

This error will happen if you update your android `SDK` but still using a `support-v4` file which belongs to an older version.
You can check your `build.gradle` (if you are using android studio) to see if `app-compact` library or `support-v4` library are set according to your latest SDK update or not. 
Also, it is possible that one of your Gradle dependencies files are using an older version of `support-v4`.

If you are using `eclipse` or some other environment in which you included `support-v4.jar`, just replace it with the latest one that you have in your SDK folder.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why this happens only on some devices ? I have millions of users and only few of them are getting this crash.

Comment: @DanyloVolokh  I am not sure why is that, but I have seen errors similar to yours when I used newer sdk features (newer build tools, compile sdk, etc) with older `support-v4`. For me, the case was using build tools and compile/target `sdk > 24` with `support-v4` of `api=23`. And there was something with `google-paly-services` too, that if I used `sdk 24`, I have to use `google-play-services>= 9.x` otherwise some similar error ("No such method error") occured.

Comment: @DanyloVolokh So, if you have other statistics of devices which have this error (thier google-play-service version for example), maybe you can come to a coclusion.

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuidler = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

Your return method:

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder updateText(String title, String message) {
    return mBuidler
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: how is this helpful ?

Comment: Maybe because he's using the Builder from `NotificationCompat`. Have you tried ?

Comment: I don't know why my answer is down voted,..!! i am using this code and working fine..please check it @DanyloVolokh

Comment: Which part of your solution is different than mine? I also use NotificationCompat.Builder. I have milions of users and only for few of them I'm getting this crash. For everybody else everything works fine. BTW: method build() will returns Notification and not Builder so probably it won't even compile.

Comment: have you tried with my code? getting same error? if yes then try to update SDK and Support library from SDK manager.

Comment: please i am helping you and you down voted my answer ..:(